# How to apply 'first-slide-active' class to Slick carousel container when first slide is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I need to apply a hook using CSS when the first slide is active in a [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carousel.

How can I make it so `.first-slide-is-active` will always appear on the wrapper element, `.carousel`?

Here's what I've tried, but it isn't working. It needs to work upon page load and when changing slides.

Please note: there can be multiple carousels within the same page.

```
$('.carousel').slick( {
  onAfterChange: function(slider,index) {
    if (index === 0) {
      slider.addClass('first-slide-is-active');
    } else {
      slider.removeClass('first-slide-is-active');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: where does "i" comes from, you have index passed in the callback but not the short "i"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should help, callback methods are depricated according to the docs and events are used. 'onAfterChange' is now 'afterChange'.

```
$('.carousel').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    if (currentSlide === 0) {
        console.log('First element');
        $(this).eq(currentSlide).addClass('first-slide-is-active');
    } else {
        $(this).eq(currentSlide).removeClass('first-slide-is-active');
    }
});
```

Full working example below:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-theme.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="carousel" height="50px">
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel" height="50px">
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.carousel').slick({
                'setting-name': 'setting-value'
            });


            $('.carousel').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide) {
                if (currentSlide === 0) {
                    console.log('First element');
                    $(this).eq(currentSlide).addClass('first-slide-is-active');
                } else {
                    $(this).eq(currentSlide).removeClass('first-slide-is-active');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. There seems to be an issue due to having multiple carousels on the same page. Any ideas as to how to get it to refer to the one that the user is interacting with?

Comment: ah too bad, well you can set them different class names and make event handler for each.. not sure if this will help

Comment: @Cofey updated, the first element is still recognizable, if this is not helping  good luck with finding solution